# How to prevent multiple click on tab for focusing on AutoSuggestBoxView?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tabs, autosuggest

I have a Form in which there are many labels and textfield. So I'm navigating within the textfield or entry by clicking on tab button in my keyboard. The normal entry is getting focused on single click whereas the AutoSuggestBoxView which is a custom entry needs two clicks on tab to get focused. I don't know why I'm facing this issue. I have applied tabindex as 0 and -1 but still it is not working.This is my xaml code

```
<CtrlUC:UCCurrentLocation Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="32" Grid.Column="0" Latitude="{Binding FieldsData.fromlatitude.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" Longitude="{Binding FieldsData.fromlongitude.Value,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" WidthRequest="400" Title="Location" LatitudeTitle="Latitude" LongitudeTitle="Longitude" ButtonText="Location" IsEditable="False" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.FromLocationControl.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.IsViolationCreated.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <local:AutoSuggestBoxView x:Name="FromState" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TabIndex="-1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromState.Value.DisplayField}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromState.Value.ValueField}" SearchMemberPath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromState.Value.DisplayField}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromState.Value.DataSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromStateSelectedItem.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromstatePropertyText.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromstatename.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Enter State" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.IsViolationCreated.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromState.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <local:CCEntry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource FormEntryStyle}" Margin="0,0,10,3" Text="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromstatecode.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromstatecode.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.LblFromStateCodeValue.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <local:AutoSuggestBoxView x:Name="FromCity" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" TabIndex="" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromCity.Value.DisplayField}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromCity.Value.ValueField}" SearchMemberPath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromCity.Value.DisplayField}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromCity.Value.DataSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromCitySelectedItem.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromcityPropertyText.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromcityname.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Enter City" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.IsViolationCreated.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromCity.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <local:CCEntry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource FormEntryStyle}" Margin="0,0,10,3" Text="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromcitycode.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromstatecode.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.LblFromCityCodeValue.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <local:AutoSuggestBoxView x:Name="FromCounty" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" TabIndex="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromcounty.Value.DisplayField}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromcounty.Value.ValueField}" SearchMemberPath="{Binding FieldsData.PickerFromcounty.Value.DisplayField}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromcounty.Value.DataSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromCountySelectedItem.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromcountyPropertyText.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromcountyname.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Enter County" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.IsViolationCreated.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.PickerFromcounty.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <local:CCEntry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Style="{StaticResource FormEntryStyle}" Margin="0,0,10,3" Text="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromcountycode.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=FieldsData.fromstatecode.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Path=FieldsData.LblFromCountyCodeValue.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

So as you can see in code the normal entry like CCEntry takes only one tab click. But the custom entry AutoSuggestBoxView takes two clicks on tab to get focused.I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to avoid multiple clicks in xamarin.forms is you have to use a boolean flag as shown below

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public isClicked = false;

    public MyPage()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        isClicked = false;
    }

    private void ItemTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(isClicked)
            return;

        isClicked = true;
        //Do your work here
    }
}
```

I am using this way to avoid multiple clicks.